# post to twitter

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Im looking for a function to post to twitter users posts they make on my website. For example

Message: "hello world" [twitter]
Click twitter and it posts message along with page URL. If the mesaage is longer than the twitter max then it shows a abbreviated version.

I at the momment i have an official one that only posts the whole page to twitter and not an individual post/message

This is what ive tried

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text"<?php echo $row['id']; echo $row['message']; ?>">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><br/>
```

But its still just displaying page name and link to page. Not the post

Can anyone help how to do this and where to get it?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Twitter API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc).  And more specifically, [Authenticating Requests with OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth).

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Tweet button by providing the correct url parameters to the widget script

the parameters that you are interested in are: data-text & data-url

For example:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://someurl.com" data-text="hello world" data-count="vertical" data-via="richerd">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

You can check out the documentation for the tweet button at: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton